# if condition 0 upto 100

Tags: php, php-5.6

I am the new PHP developer,now i want write if condition like 0 to 25 means i want show different color and 25 to 50 means i want show different color....Upto 100 i want show like this

```
<?php
    $number = 12 //here value it will come 1 to 100,bassed on $number we have write if condition and and show the different color 
?>
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more about what you need?

Comment: $number ="10" or "15" or "28" or "90" like this it will be there,now write if condition $number == "1 to 25" means i want to show different color $number == "50" means i want show diff color

Comment: still I am not sure about the requirement. From what I understood, the answer from @Ghanshyam Katriya will work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 

if($number >= 1 && $number <= 25){
      // code for number between 1 to 25
}
else if($number >= 26 && $number <= 50){
      // code for number between 26 to 50
}
else if($number >= 51 && $number <= 100){
      // code for number between 51 to 100
}
?>
```